# UDP, Samsung S4. App stopped on socket.send()

Tags: android, udp

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    byte sendData[] = new byte[1024];
    String sentence = "Hey!";
    sendData = sentence.getBytes();
    int ret = 0;
    try {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.11");
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new 
            DatagramPacket(sendData,4, IPAddress,4202);
        socket.send(sendPacket);
        socket.close();
    }
```

The code works if `socket.send` is commented out.

Manifest contains:
`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run socket.send it will give NerworkOnMainThread exception if you run that code in onCreate method or on UI thread,

Try to create thread like

```
  private LinkedBlockingQueue<DatagramPacket> writeQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<DatagramPacket>();

private Thread sendThread = new Thread() {
    private boolean shouldStop = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!shouldStop) {
            if ((finshed) && (writeQueue.size() == 0)) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                DatagramPacket packet = writeQueue.take();
                if (socket == null) {
                    shouldStop = true;
                } else {
                    socket.send(packet);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                shouldStop = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                shouldStop = true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```